# PHP Extension Not Showing

Tags: php, module, lapack

I've managed to install LAPACK (https://github.com/ianbarber/php-lapack/blob/master/README.md) on my Ubuntu server, and enabled automatic loading. In fact, phpinfo() shows that "lapack" is loaded.

However, when I try to use any method from it, it gives me a "class not found" error. I tried to get loaded extensions, and indeed, lapack is not loaded, and neither is it shown when I write php -m in the terminal.

My question is, how do I load it correctly and use it?

---

I have managed to run it as follows:

```
php -c "/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini" -f testcase.php
```

The testcase script works correctly. However, if I remove the -c directive, it does not find the extension.

Comment: where did you run phpinfo? Under a web-based script, or from the CLI? you might have enabled lapack in ONLY the cli .ini file, leaving the web/sapi version in the dust.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I'm running a web-based script. Could you please check out my edit?

Comment: have you restarted your apache server?

Comment: php -i/phpinfo() will tell you which .ini files were loaded. make sure lapack is listed in the relevant ones.

Comment: I feel like stupid now. Thanks for putting me on the right track. I didn't know that the web server and the CLI use different php.ini, first time using a server. Thank you!